# fontawesomefx not fully loaded in Gluon SceneBuilder 10

Tags: javafx, font-awesome, scenebuilder, gluon

When trying to load the Fontawesomefx jar in Gluon SceneBuilder, not all modules are loaded.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnEOI.png)

I have tried using multiple jar files without any luck.

I'm using Os X 10.12.6 / Gluon Scene Builder 10 / OpenJDK 11.0.1.

The latest version of SceneBuilder can't be installed on my Os version.

Does anyone now how I can fix this?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when for the first time load JFoenix jar file, not all module included. When i restart my computer, then all module appear. I think it's a bug